# How to test chrome app payments without paying for app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

I've created chrome packaged app(which uses chrome web store payments) and want to test how my payment implementation works. How to check it without actually buying my own app?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/google_wallet.html

> For Apps, you must call `buy()` with an extra parameter called `parameters`. This parameter currently has one field, `env`, which specifies the environment in which to process a payment. You can set this field to either `prod` (production server that accepts real credit cards), or `sandbox` (test server that accepts test credit cards to simulate transactions). The default setting is `sandbox`.

Comment: And how to make purchase from chrome web store using sandbox mode?
I'm not gonna sell from the app itself, so I wanna test app store buy button.

Comment: This is no longer supported on the webstore, using any value other than 'prod' return 'ENV_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERROR'.